# Django ORM QuerySet intersection by a field

Tags: sql, django, django-models, django-orm

These are the (pseudo) models I've got.

```
Blog:
  name
  etc...

Article:
  name
  blog
  creator
  etc

User (as per django.contrib.auth)
```

So my problem is this: I've got two users. I want to get all of the articles that the two users published on the *same* blog (no matter which blog). I can't simply filter the Article model by both users, because that would yield the set of Articles created by both users. Obviously not what I want. but can I filter somehow to get all of the articles where a *field* of the object matches between the two querysets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a great question for exercising Django's ORM :-)

Depending on which parameters are known in advance, there are a couple ways to approach this.

**Scenario 1: You know the users and the specific blog**

If you have one particular blog in mind and want to simple find all articles written by either author, you can use a Q object. I don't think this is your scenario, but I'll put it here just in case:

```
from django.db.models import Q
Article.objects.filter(Q(creator=user1) | Q(creator=user2), blog=some_blog_instance)
```

**Scenario 2: You know only the users**

If you want to find all blogs where both users have published, and want to then find which articles they've published in those blogs, you'd want to start from the `Blog` model:

```
from django.db.models import Q

# Find all blogs where both user1 and user2 have written articles
blogs = Blog.objects.filter(article__creator=user1).\
        filter(article__creator=user2).distinct()

# Now find which articles those were
for blog in blogs:
    articles = blog.article_set.filter(Q=(creator=user1) | Q=(creator=user2))
```

---

Edit based on Paulo's comments:

Here is a test set of models that I believe matches the OP's pseudo code and which demonstrates the above code working (at least on sqlite3 and postgres):

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Article(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Then some data where both user1 and user2 write articles on blog2:

```
u1 = User.objects.create(username='u1')
u2 = User.objects.create(username='u2')

b1 = Blog.objects.create(name='b1')
b2 = Blog.objects.create(name='b2')
b3 = Blog.objects.create(name='b3')

b1_art1 = Article.objects.create(name='b1_art1', blog=b1, creator=u1)
b2_art1 = Article.objects.create(name='b2_art1', blog=b2, creator=u1)
b2_art2 = Article.objects.create(name='b2_art2', blog=b2, creator=u2)
```

The query:

```
[b.name for b in Blog.objects.filter(article__creator=user1).\
    filter(article__creator=user2).distinct()]
```

produces:

```
[b2]
```

And the SQL is (my test django app was named foo):

```
SELECT "foo_blog"."id", "foo_blog"."name" 
FROM "foo_blog" 
INNER JOIN "foo_article" ON ("foo_blog"."id" = "foo_article"."blog_id") 
INNER JOIN "foo_article" T4 ON ("foo_blog"."id" = T4."blog_id") 
WHERE ("foo_article"."creator_id" = 1  AND T4."creator_id" = 2 )
```

So, while the `WHERE` clause does have `(A AND B)`, `A` and `B` reference different inner joins (`"foo_article"."creator_id"` vs. `T4."creator_id"`), and not the same table (which is what filter(A, B) would generate, (ie: `WHERE ("foo_article"."creator_id" = 1 and "foo_article"."creator_id" = 2)`)

(Without the `distinct()` clause, if you added more articles for either author, you'd get multiple `b2` entries in the queryset results.)

Like I said, it's a great ORM exercise!

Comment: -1: seems like `creator=user1 AND creator=user2` will be always false.

Comment: @paulo have a look at the SQL that django generates for `filter().filter()` using `django.db.connection.queries`... it does two inner joins (which is also why `distinct()` is added), and is different than `filter(creator=user1, creator=user2)`.

Comment: at least in my setup (Django 1.2.1 with MySQL) this results in a single inner join with `WHERE (filter1 AND filter2)`. Seems like a logical optimization to me...

Comment: ok, tricky one, this works as you said depending on the FK direction (master.filter(detail) != detail.filter(master)). I got the same result with or without distinct.

Comment: this is simpler than raw SQL. Personally I'm a bit astonished that blog.filter(article).filter(article) is not consistent with article.filter(blog).filter(blog). Scary!

Answer (score 1):

I remember to read something like "Django ORM you get you there 85% of the time, the other 15% is [raw SQL](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries)" in a presentation by someone from the core team - but I can't find the source anymore.

Your problem seems to fit [that 15% of raw SQL](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries).

Comment: I was hoping to avoid this, but I'm thinking this'll be my most likely option.

Comment: @Sri Raghavan I was like this at first too. But after a while a had to face it: ORM is there only for most simple queries. When you have to do something complex, you will have to go into raw SQL.